# How to delete a column in SqlAlchemy?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy, pycharm

I have created psql db and a table named 'Students' and given data like

```
NAME(PK)   AGE  DIVISION   GRADE
--------   ---  --------   -----
John        10     5       First
Sam          5     1       Second
Kooper      15    10       First
```

I need to delete sam's age from the table.

Comment: You want to set Sam's age to NULL, which corresponds to the value `None` in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution from the replies.

`SESSION.query(students).filter(Student.Name == 'Sam').update({'AGE': None})`

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to 'delete' a single value as you have asked. In a table you can delete a column or a row but you cannot delete a single value. What you want to do is update the field to a null value. Something like this.

```
UPDATE Students
SET AGE = NULL
WHERE NAME = Sam;
```

Comment: Thanks, man. I have a thought like that to add a Null value.